# Whose all efforts vs All whose efforts

Tags: adjectives, determiners, adjective-order

> 1. He is a fortunate person **whose all efforts** succeed.
> 2. He is a fortunate person **all of whose efforts** succeed.

Which sentence is correct? My grammar book is saying second sentence is correct. But why sentence one is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OP's second example *(He is a fortunate person **all of whose efforts** succeed)* is fine, but not the first. HOWEVER - if we compare it to a very similar form...

> (OP) *He is a fortunate person **whose all efforts** succeed* <===NOT ACCEPTABLE
>    (ME) *He is a fortunate person **whose every effort** succeeds* <=== [PERFECTLY OKAY](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22whose%20every%20project%22)

That "okay" link above is to people *whose every **project** succeeds [or goes horribly wrong]*, but it's the same basic construction - that's to say, ***Subject's every NP***, which is stylised shorthand for emphatic / explicitly-specified ***each and every one of Subject's NPs***.

---

Note that in contexts where the ***effort/s*** is/are being ***made*** (as opposed to being "possessed"), the two highlighted terms are effectively equivalent and interchangeable...

> *I will make **all efforts** to solve the problem*  <=== BOTH
>    *I will make **every effort** to solve the problem*  <=== FINE

---

It's not obvious to me why both forms are okay in that second pair, but not the first. Perhaps there is some rational "explanation" for the difference (or at least, a way of describing things so it's easy to remember what works and what doesn't). But my guess it it's just random quirks in how "acceptable" syntax has evolved.